# Storing a human consciousness in a flash drive or similar piece of technology

Tags: science-fiction, dystopia

In a dystopian trilogy I'm writing, I want to include a way to have the government store a person's ideas in a small piece of technology. 
Basically, the government has a test of strength after you have passed a test of intelligence. Those who are considered smart, but don't pass the test of strength are put into a coma and their intelligence stored in a flash drive or something similar until the government can pick it up and use it in a giant think tank of sorts. (they also collect the body to convert the mass to energy) I'm wondering about the logistics of this. Is this possible? (The story is set in the far future) The entire book has some pretty advanced technology, but nothing is explained in great depth as it's told from the main character's point of view, and they are inept at using any technology, so the book won't have an in-depth explanation of this concept.

Comment: This was done in the Neuromancer and Ghost in the Shell. Not much suspension of disbelief needed ;)

Comment: Two for two! This is a good example of what happens when you, the new contributor, don't bother to learn about a community before participating!  Again, you're creeping too close to the "story based" problem. You're also asking too many questions. SE is a one question at a time deal. (You are welcome to break up a query...

Comment: ...like this into multiple ***worldbuilding related*** questions!)  Essentially, the answer to this kind of plot question comes down to [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/what-is-narrative-necessity-and-how-does-it-apply-to-worldbuilding) --- it is so, because the story needs it to be so. VTC.

Comment: If you never explain how the technology works, then it's effectively magic and is, by definition, possible because you, the author, say it is. I'm unclear what you're expecting to get out of asking this question.

Comment: Minor detail, but "collect the body to turn the mass to energy" - unless mass is in critically short supply (a spacecraft or space habitat, maybe), an unwanted body is far more likely to be mulched than to be used for energy.

Comment: @jdunlop or sold for $160 /s  http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/april12011/

Comment: Please try to refrain from accepting an answer within 24 to 48 hours of asking a question. First of all, your question isn't a good fit for WB and is in imminent danger of closure, so answers won't be a good fit either; second, accepting an answer too soon tends to put other people off. You end up limiting the pool of potentially useful answers this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Intelligence is difficult to understand. Despite over a century's worth of pop psychology theories, we simply don't understand it. If we did, we could use that understanding to construct a true artificial intelligence/consciousness.

So, depending on how you want your story to work, this may or may not be a plausible plot point. Is intelligence merely a factor of the "software"? If so, then it could be stored in an artificial device. But if intelligence has something to do with the physical structure of the brain involved, then clearly that won't work. Additionally if intelligence is software-only and they understand it well enough to download and store it on artificial devices, why keep any particular intelligence? They could take one and modify it to super-genius levels, and make a thousand copies of that... organic, evolved intelligences wouldn't be anything special any more.

You almost need a plot point that allows them to download/store these without actually understanding the process itself. Discovered alien technology, perhaps. Or some other reason to keep them (which doesn't have to be a a rational reason).

All the other details mentioned in other answers are fluff. Easily ignored.

Answer (score 6):

Its going to take a ton of data, a metric ton.

To illustrate some of the problems, lets switch our memories and knowledge with each other without changing our brain.

The smallest problems we'll have is that our brains are wired differently. Maybe I have a brain layout that gives me a knack for languages and I have learned a few. But your brain doesnt, so now when I'm trying to speak the languages I've learned and have the knowledge for I suddenly have a lot more trouble accessing all of it. On the other hand you suddenly have it far easier to use the languages you've learned, but dont have the knowledge to speak more (yet). This goes back to your formative years, where paths in your brain that are used often will get more connections and more streamlined connections while paths that see little use get reduced for energy efficiency.

A larger problem is access. When you try to access some memory or piece of knowledge you send messages through your brain through somewhat predetermined paths. These paths are again determined through the amount of use. Brains are malleable and will adapt based on these inputs throughout your life. So when you try to access a memory using my brain you might find the neural pathway goes to a different memory, accesses a memory or piece of knowledge that you dont want or the pathway you try to activate simply doesnt exist in my brain. That would likely make both of us drooling houseplants barely able to function.

The crux here: to store a consciousness you have to store EVERYTHING. The layout, every connection, the way they are positioned, the knowledge they contain, the way they are programmed to react to input and even the speed of every connection needs to be stored into the flashdrive for the consciousness to be stored completely. You are quite literally going to need to store the position, composition and behaviour of every single cell in the brain.

Another problem: none of our storage is as reliable as we may think it is. Flash drives lose a lot of its storage during use to faults and deterioration. So you are going to need to make a couple of copies simultaneously and cross-reference all the data when you rebuild the consciousness to increase the chance of getting the original consciousness with its intelligence and capabilities.

The crux of this information: you'd better have an aweful lot of storage and a pretty perfect way to rebuild it all for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

## Theoretically yes

Using current technology, this is obviously impossible for several reasons. [Stanford's website](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/cs181/projects/2010-11/DownloadingConsciousness/tandr.html) has an article discussing the challenges in depth. Here's a relevant excerpt:

> A complete map of the human brain containing detailed information
> about each neuron and synapse would occupy about 20,000 terabytes and
> require 1016 flops (floating point operations per second) of
> processing power to function.

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NT942RH) sells memory sticks with capacities up to a terabyte. In order to increase that capacity by a factor of 20,000, you'd need something new. One promising technology that could handle the load would be DNA storage. [This article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/dna-data-storage-is-closer-than-you-think/) from Scientific American argues that DNA storage is approaching reality, so it's fair game for a sci-fi book.

Comment: I think that must be a typo in the Stanford article - I suspect it means 1016 <SI unit>flops.  1016 flops is a calculator processor.  To simulate a brain, I imagine it should be teraflops or petaflops - supercomputer range.

Comment: I've found scanned recreations of books that are 100-300 megs. However, in most of these cases the proper vector/font pdf of such a book would have weighed in at only a few hundred kbytes. A map of the human brain in high res isn't the same thing as the consciousness inherent in that physical brain. So it's unclear how much storage this would require. The brain's just a very messy, ill-designed hardware implementation of a software that might be much easier to encode than keep track of how many picometers away this synapse is from that synapse.